# Shell: Run graphicsmagick convert with timeout and log the stderr

Tags: bash, shell, logging, timeout, graphicsmagick

I want to save the error messages from graphicsmagick. But if I the piping the error message it doesn't work.

```
function logging() {
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    IN="$1"
  else
    read -r IN
  fi
  echo "$IN" | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
}


SOURCEFILE="file.pdf"
DESTFILE="file.png"
timeout --preserve-status 5 gm convert -density 150 -quality 100 -define 'pdf:use-cropbox=true' $SOURCEFILE -append $DESTFILE 2>&1 | logging "$*"
echo "$?"
```

It works with this line. Then it print the error message and kill the command after 5 seconds and I get the correct return code.

```
timeout --preserve-status 5 gm convert -density 150 -quality 100 -define 'pdf:use-cropbox=true' $SOURCEFILE -append $DESTFILE
```

This is the output without piping:

```
**** Error:  An error occurred while reading an XREF table.
**** The file has been damaged.  This may have been caused
**** by a problem while converting or transfering the file.
**** Ghostscript will attempt to recover the data.
**** However, the output may be incorrect.

gm convert: quitting due to signal 51 (SIGTERM) "Terminated"...
15  # error code
```

**Update:**

With this code I could catch all error messages but still don't get the correct error code.

```
SOURCEFILE="file.pdf"
DESTFILE="file.png"
TMP=$(mktemp)
timeout --preserve-status 5 gm convert -density 150 -quality 100 -define 'pdf:use-cropbox=true' $SOURCEFILE -append $DESTFILE 2>&1 | tee $TMP
echo "$?"
logging $TMP
rm $TMP
```

Comment: echo "$IN" | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee "$LOG_FILE"

Comment: @RamanSailopal Then it overrides each time the log file and catch also only the first line.

Comment: Use tee -a for append

Comment: @RamanSailopal This helps. But it catches still only the first error line. The updated the question.